# Push a screen from a TabbedPane

Tags: blackberry-10, blackberry-cascades

How can you push a screen on top of a TabbedPane?

I know this is possible with a NavigationPane like below :

```
NavigationPane {
id: navigationPane
Page {
    Container {
        Label { 
            text: "First page"
        }
    }

    actions: [
        ActionItem {
            title: "Next page"
            onTriggered: {
                var page = pageDefinition.createObject();
                navigationPane.push(page);
attachedObjects: ComponentDefinition {
id: pageDefinition;
source: "secondpage.qml"
    }
  }
 ]
}
...
```

But I try the same on a TabbedPane and it fails because there is no push method for TabbedPanes.

The scenario is to push an about screen using Application menus.

Help..?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no metaphor for pushing a Tab onto a TabbedPane. If the Tab already exists as a child of the TabbedPane you can make it the active Tab by [calling](https://developer.blackberry.com/cascades/reference/bb__cascades__tabbedpane.html#setactivetab) `setActiveTab()`

If the Tab is not already a child of the TabbedPane you will have to [`add()`](https://developer.blackberry.com/cascades/reference/bb__cascades__tabbedpane.html#add) it first.

But it sounds like what you really want is a [Sheet](https://developer.blackberry.com/cascades/reference/bb__cascades__sheet.html)

```
Page {
attachedObjects: [
    Sheet {
        id: mySheet
        content: Page {
            Button {
                text: "Close Sheet"
                onClicked: mySheet.close()
            }
        }
    }
]
actions: [
    ActionItem {
        title: "Show Sheet"
        ActionBar.placement: ActionBarPlacement.OnBar
        onTriggered: {
           mySheet.open();
        }
    }
]
}
```

Comment: Yes, Sheets were exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much!

Comment: you're kinda awesome :)